# Deterministic Turing Machines

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

Let's say that M is a deterministic Turing Machine, can I say that for a certain input I will have the same output?
How can I demonstarte this?

Comment: "Can I say that for each input it will have the same output?" The answer to the question you asked is obviously no - a machine can calculate the square of its input and then the inputs $1$ and $2$ will have different outputs. I suspect the question you _meant_ to ask was whether the same input repeated on two different days will give the same output. The answer to _that_ is obviously yes - if you start with the same input and do the same things to it you get the same output. There may be an interpretation of your question that's not ridiculously trivial, but I can't think what it would be.

Answer (score 1):

A deterministic Turing Machine is just a machine that does only one instruction for a given input. That does not imply that there will be the same output for every input.